# Java Servlet check if a file exists or create it

Tags: java, servlets

With the folloing check I get an error... because I try to load a file that not exists... how can I do this check safely?

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/file.xml").getFile());

if(file.exists()==false){

    //CREATE THE FILE


    }

    else{

    //UPDATE THE FILE
    }
```

Comment: Which part of the code are you getting the error from? Sounds like it's the first line...

Comment: I've noticed you tagged this question as "servlets". Can you expand a little on that? Is this code run from a class that extends HttpServlet? is it called from an HttpServlet...

Answer (score 3):

`Class.getResource()` uses the class loader to return the URL of a resource inside a jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the webapp, or inside `WEB-INF/classes`, still in the webapp. You can't and must not assume this is a file. A webapp is normally deployed as a war file. And anyway, the content of this war must be kept read-only.

If you want to write to a file, use file IO, in a directory outside of the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the API for `Class.`[`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), you'll see that it returns null if this file doesn't exist. So you only need to do this:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/file.xml");
if(url == null) {
    // File does not exist
}
else {
    // File exists
}
```

As people have been saying, you are not guaranteed to be able to write to a file in that directory, so when you write make sure it is to an external location.

Comment: ok... but than how can I write it??? I can't use File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/file.xml").getFile()); as file destination

Comment: You cannot, in general, create a file on the classpath as there may be no filesystem in which to operate.  This solution is incorrect.

Comment: True, you can't do that in general. I assumed that if he was asking about looking for/creating files he is in an environment in which this can happen.

Comment: I don't understand... if the file not exists... how can I create it on the url path?

Comment: @UsiUsi: read the answers and comments: the URL doesn't necessarily point to a file. And even if it does, you must not write to this URL. Write to some external directory. And don't use Class.getResource() to get it, but simply `new File("/some/absolute/path/that/you/chose")`

Comment: ok I understand... but if I try new File ("/file.xml"); I get an error... How can I write in the same dir where is my .class file...  with the File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/file.xml").getFile()); works

Comment: For christ sake, read what you're being told. You must **not** write **anything** to the "directory" where the class files are (which is not even a directory, but a zip entry in a war file). Write to an **external** directory, outside of the web application.